# Bar chart dynamic legend in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have been traing to achieve dynamic legend when you choose something from GeneralGroup on Filter that it filters Bar chart everything that is included into GeneralGroup...

I have been doing or trying Workaround using this link:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dynamic-legend-power-bi-change-from-category-karan-gupta

..but something doesnt work properly.

I did make 2 tables using Power Query and couple of cond. columns with Flag for 0 / 1:

```
LegendMeasure = 
if(
    CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(ExpensesLegendTable[Exp2]),ALLSELECTED(ExpensesLegendTable)),CALCULATE(Actuals[PER_Actuals],ExpensesLegendTable[ExpFlag]=0),CALCULATE(Actuals[PER_Actuals],ExpensesLegendTable[ExpFlag]=1))
```

..but it doesnt work at all. On the example is "revenue" column and by me is just a index and groups with subgroups.
Is there some neat example to do this or this is one of ways to do?

This is something what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share some more information on your dataset and/or the relation between ExpensesLegendTable and Actuals? In general, if your selector on the left forces to choose one group, you can pretty much stop the tutorial at Step 1 (you don't need to append the two tables) in the LinkedIn tutorial and skip all the complications introduced through the DAX statements.
By the way -- is it possible, that you typed his code down instead of copy-pasting? In your condition, you're missing the "= 1" (to check that your current selection entails >exactly< 1 category. Shift his window a little :)

Comment: @abbasador Why not using 2nd table in PQ? Well as I posted screenshot below, I wanna have Slicer with main groups that are chaning on Bar chart (legend too). The problem is I am not getting proper infos using this approach. And you were right I missed "=1" but still didnt change a lot of my visual.

Comment: There is no harm in having >=2 tables in PQ with/without loading them into Power BI. I'm just saying that based on the screenshot you provided, you will always have one and exactly one field selected, meaning you a) don't have to go through the trouble of reattaching the original table (Karan's figure require more flexibility) and b) can heavily simplify your DAX command. His command  reads "if in the current context, you have exactly one category selected (which for all of your bars is the case), sum only the rows with Flag_TotalRows=0 (all you need), otherwise [...] (unimportant to you).